# Using a 5/8 dado stack on a "30mm" arbor

Tags: table-saw, dado

**Background**

I would like to buy a dado stack, but 30mm is hard to come buy due to laws forbidding selling them in Europe. Using them for personal use is ok, so I can order from abroad.

**Question**

I have a Dewalt DW7492 table saw with a "30mm" arbor, but it is 14mm (9/16") wide and 30mm (1") long. It uses a flange washer that centers the 30mm ID blade on the shaft.

[image: blade with flange]

[image: arbor width]

[image: arbor length]

I suspect this is the same arbor as North American models with a different flange.

Can anyone support this theory? Is there anything I should be weary of trying to do this?

**Update about the law**

This law appears to have gone in effect in 2012. You can find links to the EU  directive [here](https://osha.europa.eu/no/legislation/directives/directive-2006-42-ec-of-the-european-parliament-and-of-the-council), which is defined in Article 12.3 based on [this ISO standard](https://www.standard.no/no/Nettbutikk/produktkatalogen/Produktpresentasjon/?ProductID=1141260).

Comment: Normal North American arbors are 5/8". If it was me, I'd doublecheck yours with calipers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. How much tolerance would you think to be acceptable?

Comment: From this thread on Fine Woodworking, an alleged machinest says 0.001-0.000, which mean I would need a bushing if my arbor is indeed 14mm. https://www.finewoodworking.com/forum/changing-arbor-hole-size-on-saw-blade

Comment: Totally OT, but why in the world is a 30mm dado stack _illegal_ to sell in Europe???

Comment: One saw blade?  Fine.  Put two or more in a room together and you're asking for trouble.

Comment: @FreeMan, I don't know specifically why, but I'd like to look into that. I've heard people speculate that it is due to the lack of a riving knife and incompatibility with the time required for the blade to be stopped (and thus saw design as well). Don't really buy any of it.

Comment: @cchoe1 Meaning if there is not a tight tolerance between the blade and the arbor?

Comment: It's the fact that dado stacks often require removing or not using the few required safety measures on the saw. You end up removing or changing  the inserts, splitters, knives, etc. and for the average home gamer this can cause a series of events that ends a weekend with fewer fingers than you started with. Obviously, the careful operator will do their best to not fall into a series of unintended consequences that lead to this, but that is not how safety works. Safety is often a series of safeguards to both protect and signal to you when you are doing something interesting.

Comment: @jdv I've added links to the EU directive that outlines regulation of dado stacks on consumer saws, i.e. "multi-blade ripsawing machines with manual loading and/or unloading".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to go out on a limb and buy a stack to know for sure, and...

It fits! There is a verry small amount of play before tightened, but any less and the blades would scrape over the arbor. I believe this is a proper 5/8" arbor.

I do not know about other manufacturer's arbor dimensions, but if you have a DeWalt, you may be in luck.

If you are interested in dados and buying a contractor saw in Europe,  in addition to the arbor diameter the DWSE942 also has a long enough arbor to support the full blade/chipper stack with some (not all) of the spacers provided in the Freud 6" Pro Dado Set.[image]

Comment: So can you tell us about your results with the dado blade on the DeWalt, did you in the end use it?

Comment: @Samball It has worked flawlessly.  I've mostly cut box joints with it, and they come out perfectly. The smaller diameter blades are more than enough and, in theory, should help it break faster. It appears to break in about the same time as a standard blade.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no," but I'll elaborate.

The dimensions are very critical in this area since small variances at the arbor can have huge effects at the edge of the blade. Also the motor spindle could have been treated differently for the euro model and it could bend or break.

If the arbor is even a small fraction oversized, the blade won't fit.  If the arbor is a fraction too small it would potentially induce a variance in the blade height that could (in theory) cause the blade to bite into the wood and send it back in your direction(kickback) or in the best case just give a very poor quality cut.

There are companies that will sell you a dado set with any sized hole you want for a very small fee for the 30mm size.  I can give you my favorite, but send me a private message for that.

Comment: SE has a PM feature now? Where??? How??? It is OK (especially here at WW, it seems) to make specific product recommendations in _answers_ so long as you indicate your affiliation (or lack thereof) with the mfgr/retailer. It's not OK, however, to _ask_ for product recommendations. "Companies like ABC Corp (I'm a fan of their high quality products) can sell you a dado set with any size arbor you'd like. I think their prices are quite reasonable." or "I work for PDQ Co and we can sell you exactly what you're after." - including links is optional

Comment: Well, if it's not against the rules, then the company is Ridge Carbide.  I'm not affiliated with them in any way, but I do use their blades on every saw they make a product for.

Comment: I haven't updated the question yet, but after going to measure the arbor a second time with calipers, I found that the arbor is ground on two sides to allow the flange to groove onto it. Measuring from the outside rounded edge, it appears to be 5/8". I'd find it strange if Dewalt made its European arbor only slightly off from 5/8, intended for 30mm blades... seems asking for somebody to try this and have problems, like me :)